# Sum of a set normalize by total items in set

Tags: notation

This might be a be simple but I just want to make sure I didn't use the wrong notation.

If I have a set of weighted terms, ${w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n}$ and the score is the sum of $w_1$ to $w_n$ normalize by count of $w$. Count of $w$ is just the total number of terms, i.e. $n$. 
so, can I write:

$score = \frac{\sum{w_i}}{\left | w \right |}$ ?

p/s:  $W = \{w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n \}$ but I don't really want to introduce $W$ for the sake of showing the count using $|W|$.

Thanks.

Comment: I am cool to get a downvote like I said this is a simple question and I am clarifying it. But for the nice guy who downvoted would you be nice again and explain why do I get a downvote?

Comment: For the guys who downvoted, that's very helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't think one has to be sarcastic about that. I think the downvoter just needs you to edit your post and clarify the meaning of $w$ ;-)

Comment: @BISHD I am more that happy to edit and learn and improve the answer so that it benefits everyone else too. But NO information provided to advise how/what should I improve?

Comment: If information is missing out you could start with the information I gave you in my answer. Tell the world, what $w$ is. ;-) Otherwise you are right about the downvoter not giving any information on why he down voted it.

Comment: I did say that "I have a set of weighted terms, $w_1, w_2$... but I included more information now.

Comment: It's ok, I guess they are doing this for my good too. They want me to learn by myself through the hard way so that I will remember it by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w$ is the set of weighted terms, you are right.

Comment: $w$ is a set of weighted terms. Count of $w$ is total number of terms, i.e. $n$

Comment: Ok, sets are usually denoted by upper case, but this is just a convention.

Comment: I understand that, and $w$ is the individual item in $W$, what I want is to avoid using $W$ just because I want to show $\left | W \right |$ if it's possible

Comment: Edited my answer.